# How to "sniff" data from subscribe and still return an Observable<Response>

Tags: angular

I have this subclass of angular http and it is injected gracefuly wherever i need in my application. The thing is: i need to check some values, even if they are not http error codes, and return the Observable Response. The problem is that subscribe returns Subscription.

The purpose of this class is to, transparently, deal with some common http errors globaly (whereas http errors -> catch block; or api errors -> json fields to be checked in subscribe block).

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Request, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options)
            .catch((error: any) => {
                // Do something here, maybe some redirect.
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })
            .subscribe(res => {
                if (res.json().status === 401) {
                    // Do something here, maybe some redirect too.
                }
                return Observable.of(res);
            });
    }

}
```

I am reading the rxjs documentation, but i am still confused by many of the concepts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()` instead of subscribe, subscribe is the end of the pipe, the handler, you want to modify it.

```
.map(res => {
  if (res.json().status === 401) {
    // Do something here, maybe some redirect too.
  }
  return res;
});
```